# STM32F407VE Change/Update IP Address Issue

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, iar, stm32f407

I have a big problem to change IP Address without restart STM32F407VE.

I'm working on STM32F407VE TCP/IP ethernet protocol (IAR9.30.1).
I am able to transmit data to arm and receive to pc terminal (putty, teraterm).
I'm using project lwipWebserver.ewp .eww copied from
c:\ARM_ST_9.30.1_50027_Downloadly.ir\ST\STM32F4xx\IAR-STM32F407ZG-SK\WebServer

I copied from Examples:
from ARM_ST_9.30.1_50027_Downloadly.ir\ST\STM32F4xx 3 folders:

`IAR-STM32F407VE (previous IAR-STM32F407ZG-SK)`
`Libraries`
`STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib`

Everything works fine if I set the IP Address **192.168.1.114** only once:

main.c:

```c
u32_t ip_addr_arr[4];
ip_addr_arr[0] = 192; 
ip_addr_arr[1] = 168; 
ip_addr_arr[2] = 1; 
ip_addr_arr[3] = 114;
LwIP_Init_New(&ip_addr_arr[0]); // &ip_addr_arr[0] or ip_addr_arr
```

Windows10: cmd:

> ping 192.168.1.114

OK

But if I try to change the IP Address **from 192.168.1.114 to 192.168.1.113** while the program is running, then problems start:
it works for a few seconds, then it stops working: main.c:

```c
ip_addr_arr[0] = 192; 
ip_addr_arr[1] = 168; 
ip_addr_arr[2] = 1; 
ip_addr_arr[3] = 113;
LwIP_Init_New(ip_addr_arr); // &ip_addr_arr[0] or ip_addr_arr
```

Windows10: cmd:

> ping 192.168.1.113

Not OK

I changed  LwIP_Init to  LwIP_Init_New:
C:\ARM_STM32F407_PRJ\IAR-STM32F407VE\WebServer\app\httpserver\netconf.c

```c
void LwIP_Init_New(u32_t* ip_addr_array) // minem
{
  struct ip_addr ipaddr;
  struct ip_addr netmask;
  struct ip_addr gw;

  /* Initializes the dynamic memory heap defined by MEM_SIZE.*/
  mem_init();

  /* Initializes the memory pools defined by MEMP_NUM_x.*/
  memp_init();

#ifdef USE_DHCP
  ipaddr.addr = 0;
  netmask.addr = 0;
  gw.addr = 0;
#else
  // IP4_ADDR(&ipaddr, IP_ADDR0, IP_ADDR1, IP_ADDR2, IP_ADDR3);
  // IP4_ADDR(&ipaddr, *ip_addr0, *ip_addr1, *ip_addr2, *ip_addr3);
  IP4_ADDR(&ipaddr, ip_addr_array[0], ip_addr_array[1], ip_addr_array[2], ip_addr_array[3]);
  IP4_ADDR(&netmask, NETMASK_ADDR0, NETMASK_ADDR1 , NETMASK_ADDR2, NETMASK_ADDR3);
  IP4_ADDR(&gw, GW_ADDR0, GW_ADDR1, GW_ADDR2, GW_ADDR3);
#endif

  /* - netif_add(struct netif *netif, struct ip_addr *ipaddr,
            struct ip_addr *netmask, struct ip_addr *gw,
            void *state, err_t (* init)(struct netif *netif),
            err_t (* input)(struct pbuf *p, struct netif *netif))

   Adds your network interface to the netif_list. Allocate a struct
  netif and pass a pointer to this structure as the first argument.
  Give pointers to cleared ip_addr structures when using DHCP,
  or fill them with sane numbers otherwise. The state pointer may be NULL.

  The init function pointer must point to a initialization function for
  your ethernet netif interface. The following code illustrates it's use.*/
  netif_add(&netif, &ipaddr, &netmask, &gw, NULL, &ethernetif_init, &ethernet_input);

  /*  Registers the default network interface.*/
  netif_set_default(&netif);

  /*  When the netif is fully configured this function must be called.*/
  netif_set_up(&netif);
}
```

Would you tell me how to change the IP address to the second, third and fourth, etc. without restarting STM32F407VE?

Comment: When you searched, did you find [netif_set_ipaddr](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_0_x/group__netif__ip4.html#ga73b043a7ec0e4899aba8433ec9064cca)()?

Comment: Yes, I found. There is netif_set_ipaddr inside netif_set_addr in netif.c.
netif_set_addr is in C:\ARM_STM32F407_PRJ\IAR-STM32F407VE\WebServer\lwip_v1.3.2\src\core\netif.c.
LwIP_Init_New is in 
C:\ARM_STM32F407_PRJ\IAR-STM32F407VE\WebServer\app\httpserver\netconf.c
and LwIP_Init_New calls netif_add, then netif_add calls netif_set_addr, then netif_set_addr calls netif_set_ipaddr.

So I used netif_set_ipaddr() by calling LwIP_Init_New().
Must I call netif_set_ipaddr() directly?

Comment: Well, you can't call the init function twice. It does one-time setup stuff which can't be repeated.

Comment: Why can't I call the init function twice? Why it does one-time setup stuff which can't be repeated?

Comment: Should I use netif_set_ipaddr() instead of LwIP_Init_New()?

Comment: If I understand you correctly I must restart STM32F407VE with new IP because I  can't call the init function twice cause it does one-time setup stuff which can't be repeated, must not I?

Comment: "Why it does one-time setup stuff" ... because that's how it was written. It's an init function. No, you do not need to restart the MCU. Please refer to the sample code in the answer below which shows you the alternative.

Comment: Thank you TypeIA

Comment: Nothing is redundant: your "Please refer to the sample code in the answer below which shows you the alternative. " helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the IP address during runtime (while using static IP addressing), you need to call `netif_set_addr` followed by `netif_set_up`.

An example taken from [TivaWare](https://www.ti.com/tool/SW-TM4C):

```c
//*****************************************************************************
//
// Completes the network configuration change.  This is directly called when
// not using a RTOS and provided as a callback to the TCP/IP thread when using
// a RTOS.
//
//*****************************************************************************
static void
lwIPPrivateNetworkConfigChange(void *pvArg)
{
    uint32_t ui32IPMode;
    struct ip_addr ip_addr;
    struct ip_addr net_mask;
    struct ip_addr gw_addr;

    //
    // Get the new address mode.
    //
    ui32IPMode = (uint32_t)pvArg;

    //
    // Setup the network address values.
    //
    if(ui32IPMode == IPADDR_USE_STATIC)
    {
        ip_addr.addr = htonl(g_ui32IPAddr);
        net_mask.addr = htonl(g_ui32NetMask);
        gw_addr.addr = htonl(g_ui32GWAddr);
    }
#if LWIP_DHCP || LWIP_AUTOIP
    else
    {
        ip_addr.addr = 0;
        net_mask.addr = 0;
        gw_addr.addr = 0;
    }
#endif

    //
    // Switch on the current IP Address Aquisition mode.
    //
    switch(g_ui32IPMode)
    {
        //
        // Static IP
        //
        case IPADDR_USE_STATIC:
        {
            //
            // Set the new address parameters.  This will change the address
            // configuration in lwIP, and if necessary, will reset any links
            // that are active.  This is valid for all three modes.
            //
            netif_set_addr(&g_sNetIF, &ip_addr, &net_mask, &gw_addr);

            //
            // If we are going to DHCP mode, then start the DHCP server now.
            //
#if LWIP_DHCP
            if((ui32IPMode == IPADDR_USE_DHCP) && g_bLinkActive)
            {
                dhcp_start(&g_sNetIF);
            }
#endif

            //
            // If we are going to AutoIP mode, then start the AutoIP process
            // now.
            //
#if LWIP_AUTOIP
            if((ui32IPMode == IPADDR_USE_AUTOIP) && g_bLinkActive)
            {
                autoip_start(&g_sNetIF);
            }
#endif

            //
            // And we're done.
            //
            break;
        }

        //
        // DHCP (with AutoIP fallback).
        //
#if LWIP_DHCP
        case IPADDR_USE_DHCP:
        {
            //
            // If we are going to static IP addressing, then disable DHCP and
            // force the new static IP address.
            //
            if(ui32IPMode == IPADDR_USE_STATIC)
            {
                dhcp_stop(&g_sNetIF);
                netif_set_addr(&g_sNetIF, &ip_addr, &net_mask, &gw_addr);
            }

            //
            // If we are going to AUTO IP addressing, then disable DHCP, set
            // the default addresses, and start AutoIP.
            //
#if LWIP_AUTOIP
            else if(ui32IPMode == IPADDR_USE_AUTOIP)
            {
                dhcp_stop(&g_sNetIF);
                netif_set_addr(&g_sNetIF, &ip_addr, &net_mask, &gw_addr);
                if(g_bLinkActive)
                {
                    autoip_start(&g_sNetIF);
                }
            }
#endif
            break;
        }
#endif

        //
        // AUTOIP
        //
#if LWIP_AUTOIP
        case IPADDR_USE_AUTOIP:
        {
            //
            // If we are going to static IP addressing, then disable AutoIP and
            // force the new static IP address.
            //
            if(ui32IPMode == IPADDR_USE_STATIC)
            {
                autoip_stop(&g_sNetIF);
                netif_set_addr(&g_sNetIF, &ip_addr, &net_mask, &gw_addr);
            }

            //
            // If we are going to DHCP addressing, then disable AutoIP, set the
            // default addresses, and start dhcp.
            //
#if LWIP_DHCP
            else if(ui32IPMode == IPADDR_USE_DHCP)
            {
                autoip_stop(&g_sNetIF);
                netif_set_addr(&g_sNetIF, &ip_addr, &net_mask, &gw_addr);
                if(g_bLinkActive)
                {
                    dhcp_start(&g_sNetIF);
                }
            }
#endif
            break;
        }
#endif
    }

    //
    // Bring the interface up.
    //
    netif_set_up(&g_sNetIF);

    //
    // Save the new mode.
    //
    g_ui32IPMode = ui32IPMode;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

> u32_t ip_addr_arr[4];
> ip_addr_arr[0] = 192;
> ip_addr_arr[1] = 168;
> ip_addr_arr[2] = 1;
> ip_addr_arr[3] = 114;
> LwIP_Init_New(&ip_addr_arr[0]); // :This is OK in main.c
>
> ********* We do some work then *********
>
> // Then without restarting:
> u32_t ip_addr_arr[4];
> ip_addr_arr[0] = 192;
> ip_addr_arr[1] = 168;
> ip_addr_arr[2] = 1;
> ip_addr_arr[3] = 109;
> LwIP_Init_New(&ip_addr_arr[0]); // :This is no OK in the same session in the same main.c:

You shouldn't call `LwIP_Init_New` when the lwIP stack is already up and running. Instead, replace it with the following:

```c
void LwIP_change_ip_cfg(u32_t* ip_addr_array)
{
    struct ip_addr ipaddr;
    struct ip_addr netmask;
    struct ip_addr gw;

#ifdef USE_DHCP
    ipaddr.addr = 0;
    netmask.addr = 0;
    gw.addr = 0;
#else
    IP4_ADDR(&ipaddr, ip_addr_array[0], ip_addr_array[1], ip_addr_array[2], ip_addr_array[3]);
    IP4_ADDR(&netmask, NETMASK_ADDR0, NETMASK_ADDR1 , NETMASK_ADDR2, NETMASK_ADDR3);
    IP4_ADDR(&gw, GW_ADDR0, GW_ADDR1, GW_ADDR2, GW_ADDR3);
#endif

    /*  Set the new address parameters.*/
    netif_set_addr(&netif, &ipaddr, &netmask, &gw);

    /*  When the netif is fully configured this function must be called.*/
    netif_set_up(&netif);
}
```

Comment: You can download `SW-TM4C-2.2.0.295.exe` from the link I posted. If you don't want to install the SDK, you can simply rename the file as `SW-TM4C-2.2.0.295.zip` and extract the archive. Some lwIP examples: `.\SW-TM4C-2.2.0.295\examples\boards\ek-tm4c129exl\enet_lwip`, `.\SW-TM4C-2.2.0.295\examples\boards\ek-tm4c129exl\enet_tcpecho_server`, etc. But if I were you, I wouldn't focus too much on these examples, since they are targeted at TI's TM4C129 controllers. The code example in my answer is the glue between lwIP stack and TI API.

Comment: all the same in my program: netif_set_addr (netif_set_addr called by netif_add ) then netif_set_up

Comment: u32_t ip_addr_arr[4]; ip_addr_arr[0] = 192; ip_addr_arr[1] = 168; ip_addr_arr[2] = 1; ip_addr_arr[3] = 114; LwIP_Init_New(&ip_addr_arr[0]); 
// :This is OK in main.c
****************************************************************************************************************
*********We do some work then************************************************************
// Then without restarting:
u32_t ip_addr_arr[4]; ip_addr_arr[0] = 192; ip_addr_arr[1] = 168; ip_addr_arr[2] = 1; ip_addr_arr[3] = 109; LwIP_Init_New(&ip_addr_arr[0]);
// :This is no OK in the same session in the same main.c:

Comment: It works: void LwIP_change_ip_cfg(u32_t* ip_addr_array)
{
    struct ip_addr ipaddr;
    struct ip_addr netmask;
    struct ip_addr gw;

    IP4_ADDR(&ipaddr, ip_addr_array[0], ip_addr_array[1], ip_addr_array[2], ip_addr_array[3]);
    IP4_ADDR(&netmask, NETMASK_ADDR0, NETMASK_ADDR1 , NETMASK_ADDR2, NETMASK_ADDR3);
    IP4_ADDR(&gw, GW_ADDR0, GW_ADDR1, GW_ADDR2, GW_ADDR3);

    /*  Set the new address parameters.*/
    netif_set_addr(&netif, &ipaddr, &netmask, &gw);

    /*  When the netif is fully configured this function must be called.*/
    netif_set_up(&netif);
}
Thank you

Comment: Thank you Velvel.
void LwIP_change_ip_cfg(u32_t* ip_addr_array)
It works.